# Passing iterator's element to a function: wrong type of pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, iterator

I'm attempting to solve Project Euler's problem #3 using C++ to gain an understanding of how to use C++ iterators. According to the examples I've seen online, I can use the dereferened iterator as a parameter for `cout`, and it will print the elements successfully. By that same logic, I should be able to pass the iterator as a pointer since it points to the element I'm wanting, however this is not working as I believed it would:

Reference: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html

In the above link (the `The STL approach (use this)` segment), the author prints out the elements of his vector using

`cout<<*myIntVectorIterator<<" ";`

In my code, I try to pass the iterator as an element, however it runs into the issue of the pointer conversion:

```
 std::vector<long>::reverse_iterator it = factors.rbegin();                                                         
 for (; it != factors.rend(); ++it) {                                                                                                                  
    if(isPrime(it))                                                                                                  
    {                                                             
         std::cout << *it << std::endl;                           
         break;           
    }                                                                                                   
 return 0;
```

I'm getting the pointer conversion error:

error: cannot convert ‘std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > > >’ to ‘long int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘bool isPrime(long int*)’

Explicitly casting this pointer as a long* `if(isPrime((long *)*it))` results in a segmentation fault.

Can I get an explanation of what is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does `isPrime` take a pointer instead of just a `long`?

Comment: There's no reason I couldn't pass in the value explicitly, I suppose, however I'd like an explanation to the question for my own understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preferred option: change `isPrime` to take a `long` (and pass `*it` to it).

Secondary option: pass `&*it` instead of `it`.

Your original code doesn't work because `it` is an iterator (which is a class) whereas the function expected `long int *` and there is no implicit conversion from iterator to pointer.

`*it` invokes overloaded `operator*` on the iterator object and gives a designator for the memory location where the `long` is stored; so you can take the address of that to get a pointer to that location.

Comment: @Barry hurrah for simultaneous edits... leaving a comment might have been a better idea. I'll clean it up

Comment: Can you explain what &*it does exactly? I understand you're dereferencing the object, and then acquiring the address of it, however I don't see how the result of this is different than just `it`

Comment: @Bennett explanation is now visible

Comment: So as a follow up question:

Is the reason that `cout << *it` works but isPrime(it) does not is because cout knows how to handle that type of pointer, whereas my function is explicitly looking for a `long*`?

Comment: @Bennett `*it` is different to `it`, do you understand the difference?  That version of `cout <<` expects a `long`  ; `isPrime` would work the same way if you changed it to also expect a `long`.

Comment: @Bennet Just to clarify, `*it` is not a pointer. When you `cout << *it`, that's no different than `cout << 42`.

Comment: Yes. `it` is a pointer and *it is that pointer dereferenced (the value that `it` is pointing to). I believe I understand why passing the pointer to isPrime does not work, I'm still trying to understand why dereferencing an iterator works perfectly fine with cout.

Comment: @Bennett `it` is not a pointer. It's an object of class type. It has some overloaded operators which allow it to use similar syntax to what can be used with pointers.

Comment: @Bennett: iterators are not pointers, they have unary `operator*` (and `operator->`) overloaded to allow them to be used like pointers.  Ditto for smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @Bennett `cout << it;` would be analogous to your `isPrime(it)`.  You will find that that doesn't work either.

Comment: So in that same train of logic, when I do cout<<*it, I'm not dereferencing `it`, but performing an overloaded operation that happens to use an asterisk?

Comment: @Bennett, Yes, it just does a similar operation to dereferencing, so that operator was chosen. Iterators are like glorified pointers in some ways. You can, at the very least, move to the next element and get the value referred to by the iterator. Both mimic pointer operations and use the same syntax.

Comment: @Bennet An iterator acts like a pointer.  It has an overloaded `*` operator so that pointer and iterator *syntax* (note the word *syntax*) can be used.

Comment: @Bennett we still use the term "dereference" with iterators even though it's not exactly the same as dereferencing a raw pointer

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit conversion from type `std::vector<T>::recerse_iterator` to type `T *`.

So you have explicitly to pass a pointer to the function

```
if ( isPrime( &*it ) )
```

Also you could indeed use pointers instead of the iterator. For example

```
for ( long *p = factors.data() + factors.size(); p != factors.data();  )   
{
    if ( isPrime( --p ) )
    {                                                             
         std::cout << *p << std::endl;                           
         break;           
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `;;` in your loop a typo, or is there some syntax that allows 4 fields in a for loop that I'm not aware of?